# Where i do look up the file in the iCloud which i m sending to it?

Tags: icloud

I am sending photos to iCloud and in my settings my apps iCloud option is checked.

It is retrieving data but when i opened the iCloud from the noting shows.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/12779/icloud-and-uidocument-beyond-the-basics-part-1

i had follw this tutorial